# Android 11 Runtime Storage Permission

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-permissions, android-11

Android 11 (R) skip my permission request but all the work is going on without permission. I gave my code below. I tryed many code but doesnot work properly. Please help me

[I need this type of permission dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrXkY.jpg)

```
     int m_permit = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (m_permit != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        Permission(context);
    }




public void Permission(Context context) {

    final Dialog dialog;

    final Activity activity = (Activity) context;


    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View view= li.inflate(R.layout.dialog_permission, null);
        dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog);
        dialog.setContentView(view);

        TextView ok = view.findViewById(R.id.ok);
        dialog.show();

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();

                int m_permit = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

                if (m_permit != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(activity,
                            STORAGE_PERMISSION,
                            1);
                }
            }
        });
}
```